# has_many through form and adding attribute to join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form, has-many-through

This is my first stakoverflow question and fairly new to Rails. I've searched through previous similar questions but can't seem to figure this one out. I have a has_many through relationship with Users and Accounts and I have an extra boolean attribute "account_admin" on the UserAccount model (join table). I'm trying to figure out how to set this when I create a new Account.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_accounts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :accounts, :through => :user_accounts
  ..
end
```

Account:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_accounts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_accounts
end
```

UserAccount:

```
class UserAccount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
  # includes account_admin boolean
end
```

I would like to be able to create an account, assign users to that account, and designate an account_admin all in one form. I have this so far which allows me to select the users in an account but I'm not sure how to set the account_admin boolean here as well.

```
= simple_form_for @account do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :description
  = f.association :users, label_method: :to_label, :as => :check_boxes
  = f.button :submit
```

Appreciate any tips. Thanks

Comment: Do you want more than one admin for an account or just one admin per account?

Comment: There can be multiple admins for an account. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Account model:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description,  :user_accounts_attributes
  has_many :user_accounts, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :users, :through => :user_accounts
  has_many :user_without_accounts, :class_name => 'User', :finder_sql => Proc.new {
       %Q{
         SELECT *
         FROM users where id NOT IN (Select user_id from user_accounts where account_id = #{id})
       }
   }

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_accounts, reject_if:  proc { |attributes| attributes['user_id'] == '0' }

 def without_accounts
    new_record? ? User.all :  user_without_accounts
 end
end
```

#### In form:

```
= simple_form_for @account do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.input :description
  - @account.user_accounts.each do |user_account|
  = f.simple_fields_for :user_accounts, user_account do |assignment|
    = assignment.check_box :user_id
    = assignment.label :user_id, user_account.user.name rescue raise  user_account.inspect
    = assignment.input :account_admin
    %hr
  - @account.without_accounts.each do |user|
    = f.simple_fields_for :user_accounts, @account.user_accounts.build do |assignment|
    = assignment.check_box :user_id
    = assignment.label :user_id, user.name
    = assignment.input :account_admin
    %hr
  = f.button :submit
```

Comment: Thanks this is close. I'd like the ability to assign multiple users to the account which is why I had :as => :check_boxes in the original. Would there be a way to present each user as a check box and then another check box for account_admin?

Comment: I've edited my answer which works, Here is a  demo project containing this example: https://github.com/railscash/sample_change_user_role

Comment: Awesome - I think there is a small bug still. I tried out your github project and it is inserting the same user_id twice into user_accounts when I check box two different users. Do you know what might be going on?

Comment: this is the basic thing, you can modify it using some validations, etc. Regarding the duplicate user_id, you can check the two blocks in account form, I guess there is a redundancy in those two blocks, you can have a try with fresh database. Hope that helps