# Assigning attributes to a join table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through, has-many

In my app, **users** can create **modules** ("mods" to avoid reserved naming) and can group them in **modulegroups**.

```
class User
  has_many :modulegroups
  has_many :mods, through :modulegroups

class Modulegroup
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :mod

class Mods
  has_many :modulegroups
  has_many :users, through :modulegroups
```

However, users should also be able to define the **order** mods appear in with respect to their module group. So I want to add an attribute, "rank" to each mod with respect to the group.

Because the same mod can have a different rank in one group than in another, it shouldn't be a column in the mods table, nor in the user's table. How would I define these ranks?

The closest answer on SO I can find to this is this one: [has_many through form and adding attribute to join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300152/has-many-through-form-and-adding-attribute-to-join-table)

But my needs are a bit different and I'd prefer not to stick in an ugly SQL statement in the model. That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this right by adding in one more association. As you have set it up, you can't have a `Mod` in more than `Modulegroup`. Try this:

A `Modulegroup` should have many `Mods` and a `Mod` should belong to a `Modulegroup`.

What it sounds like you want to do is take this even further.

You want to create a new model, say `ModelgroupMod` which has two columns. These are `module_group_id` and `mod_id`. (we'll add rank in a sec)

Now you change the associartions again.

```
class Modulegrpoup
   has_many :mods, through: :modelgroup_mod

class Mod
  has_many :mods, through: :modelgroup_mod

class ModulegroupMod
   belongs_to :modulegroup
   belongs_to :mod
```

Now that you have this, you can add the `rank` column to `ModulegroupMod` and you can set a rank that is unique in every `Modulegroup` through the `has_many, through` call.

The SQL statement in from the other link is totally unnecessary because they're doing something that is a little different. What you might want to add though is a scope to `ModuegroupMod` where you order by `rank`.

```
default_scope :order('rank)
```

Comment: Ah, okay. So now I can just make ``rank`` a property of ``ModulegroupMod``?

Comment: Exactly. I added a little but to the answer.

Comment: For anyone else with this problem, Harvest's Ranked-Model gem is an excellent solution for scoping ranks: https://github.com/mixonic/ranked-model